# How I can find where page can't end to load?

Tags: php, html

I have a page that doesn't end to load. PHP max_execution_time is set to 30 but the icon in the Chrome tab doesn't end to turn. What tool I can use to find where the script is?

PHP log are clean, and this is a simple login page made using laravel.
I discover that problm are caused by cookie, in fact if I load page using Chrome hidden mode I have not the problem.

Comment: Have you checked the server error logs? Done any basic debugging?

Comment: `die('Fine until here');` will probably be the most reasonable strategy in most cases.

Comment: What code causes the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP max execution time is for PHP. There are several other things that have to process as well, like MySQL. The time it takes SQL to do stuff is not included in the PHP max execuion time. Beyond that, you'd have to show some code to figure out why.

To anwser your question, the browser is a pretty good tool for that. Or if a rewrite is hiding the filename you could grep for a unige string from the source, assuming you know which parts are PHP generated.